# Spring MVC - Spring Security - Controllers General Architecture - Best practices

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, architecture, controller, spring-security

Recently i am trying to learn Spring. I have created a simple webapp which basically should have 2 types of users:

- Customer
- Admin

You can imagine the app as a classic shopping webapp, where admins have the privileges to add new items, and the customers can see the listed items and add to their shopping carts.
My Question is now about the **general architecture of the system**, which should be one of the best practice examples of Spring Framework.

I can list here the points about this architectural decisions and you can tell me whether you would do these in another way:

**1-** I have 2 different dispatcher servlets. So the urls under public will be for customers and admin will be for admins.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>public-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/public/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>admin-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**2-** In Spring-Security.xml i have an authentication for admin like this:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
```

(All actions under the url /admin/ will be password protected)

**3-** Each Servlet has a viewResolver pointing a different folder, which contains jsps:

```
/WEB-INF/admin-jsp/  (admin jsps)
/WEB-INF/public-jsp/  (customer jsps)
```

**4-** Lets say i have these Domain Objects: Item, ShoppingCart, Customer etc. For each domain object i have ONE Controller class i.e. ItemController which handles whole requests (customers and admins) about an item.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/item")
@SessionAttributes({"cart"})
public class ItemController { ...
```

Each of these decisions, makes sense when i think about them one by one. But in reality, it is clear that as i did not see any big Spring application (internet contains lots of small code parts which do not give an idea about the whole), there is something wrong here..

For Instance: I can call this url as a customer /public/item/addNewItem (which is actually there for admins), and the method will be executed since ItemController (/item) is visible for everybody. But since i have jsps in 2 different locations, spring will throw the error that the View is not there.
Similarly as an admin when i can call the url /admin/item/addToCart....

What is the best arch. of implementing the whole? Should i have defined some more urls in security configuration? For example:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
<intercept-url pattern="/admin/addNewItem" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
```

OR

Should i have defined different Controllers for different roles?

```
 @RequestMapping("/public/item")
    @SessionAttributes({"cart"})
    public class PublicItemController { ...

 @RequestMapping("/admin/item")
    public class AdminItemController { ...
```

OR

Any other way? How should it be done in a big system where lots of roles, controllers etc. take place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know I am late to this discussion (you might have solved your problem by now), but here this is for all the late comers like me :)

With Spring security (or any security framework) we usually control the access to our application "RESOURCES"(which are accessible through the application URLs) and for that we need a ROLE-TO-RESOURCE mapping.

1. It is not a good approach to have 2 different dispatcher servlets, unless you have a very STRONG reason for that. And to use "Spring Security", one is enough.
2. This is the approach you should start with, allowing access to URL patterns based on user ROLEs. Spring security framework classes are there to check the user ROLEs before allowing access to the requested URL.
3. We are securing logical resources, we are anyway not allowing users to access our physical resources directly. Keep your JSPs inside WEB-INF and you are good to go.
4. You don't need to have different Controllers for different ROLEs. Controller methods are there to serve web requests and if the user is not allowed to access a particular URL, your Controller method serving that URL will never get executed.

Answer (score 2):

1. Generally in Spring apps you have one dispatcher servlet. I dont think having one for public requests and one for admin requests buys you anything.
2. Yep, sounds good
3. Again, I dont see how splitting admin and public JSPs into separate directories is going to help you. It might end up confusing you if you have JSPs that are common to both areas
4. It depends on your personal preference. I define my security stuff in XML, but plenty of people prefer annotations

Comment: Thank you. 4. point is actually more about Controller Class count pro Domain Object, than Annotation based configuration ;)

Comment: Ah, OK.In that case I'd probably have separate controllers for the admin and public item controllers.

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting approach. You can solve your actual problem by defining two different lists of controllers for each dispatcher servlet. There are multiple ways to archive it, for example:

1. Instead of using component scan declare each contoller manually in XML.
2. If you have few exceptions then you can use [filters](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-scanning-filters). Create two new annotations, `OnlyForAdminController` and `OnlyForPublicController`. Annotate corresponding classes. Then customize component scan options for each dispatcher servlet:

```xml
<!-- For public  -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.yourproject.conrollers">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="com.yourproject.annotation.OnlyForAdminController"/>
</context:component-scan>


<!-- For admin  -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.yourproject.conrollers">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="com.yourproject.annotation.OnlyForPublicController"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

In real systems of this type (e-shop) most of the time you will have some special requirements for public and admin users. For example in a case of `ItemController` admin user may see some sale statistics as additional info, where public user may see a list of 5 previously viewed items. So from perfomance point of view you will have two separate controllers. In any case you can start reuse some controllers where it possible and split these controllers per user later when some special behavior will be requested. Your technique will be much more interesting when you have only minor differencies between two types of users.